# How can I modify the shortcode values of a nextgen gallery using php?

Tags: php

I am trying to modify the parameters of a NextGen gallery shortcode when displayed in a theme template.

I paste the shortcode into an ACF WYSIWYG field like this

```
[ngg src="galleries" ids="202" display="basic_thumbnail" images_per_page="20"]
```

The gallery is then displayed on a screenshot page which is fine.

However, I would like to also display a set amount of images from the gallery on a different page/different theme template file.

I was wondering if it is possible, using PHP, to change the images_per_page parameter. Rather than pasting a second shortcode.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that NextGen Gallery uses the third parameter (ie, `$shortcode`) in their [`shortcode_atts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) call, you can filter the attributes using the [`shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shortcode_atts_shortcode/) (in your case it'll probably be `shortcode_atts_ngg`). You can probably find out more from the plugin's support team, or by perusing its source code.